# NodeJS - Problem when parsing JSON string inside another JSON on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, windows

My nodejs application receives an argument that contains a JSON string as value. For example:

```
node index.js --json-items='[{"a": 10, "b": 20}]'
```

And inside **index.js**:

```
const { jsonItems } = argv
const items = JSON.parse(jsonItems)
// Works...
```

So I made it automatic via **package.json** scripts (JSON scaped):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node index.js --json-items='[{\"a\": 10, \"b\": 20}]'"
   }
}
```

On my MacOS it still working because the arg is scaped correctly:

```
const { jsonItems } = argv
// (string) '[{"a": 10, "b": 20}]'
```

But on a Windows it doesn't because double quotes are removed:

```
const { jsonItems } = argv
// (string) '[{a: 10, b: 20}]'
// JSON.parse() -> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token...
```

**How to resolve this?**

Or just how to convert before `JSON.parse()`:

```
'[{a: 10, b: 20}]' -> '[{"a": 10, "b": 20}]'
```

> I'm using [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) package to get the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with how Windows and NPM and then finally Node handle the quotes.

```
"dev": "node index.js --json-items=\"[{\\\"a\\\": 10, \\\"b\\\": 20}]\""
```

You first need to escape it once for the json, and then you need to escape it again for windows/node. Also `'` does not seem to work too good either so I recommend `\"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to wrap double quotes around each Object Key, so you could just us this before the `JSON.parse()`

```js
let validJSON = '[{a: 10, b: 20}]'.replace(/([{,])(\s*)([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+?)\s*:/g, '$1"$3":')

console.log(validJSON);
console.log(JSON.parse(validJSON));
```